# passing a string value from one view controller to a second variable view controller Xcode

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5

I have an app in which I am loading variable view controllers depending on where the user is in the app.  This is my code.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;{
    if (mission <1) {
    gameViewController *detailViewController = [[gameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"gameViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        detailViewController.which2 = which;
    }
    else if (mission > 0) {
    NSString *viewController = @"gameViewController";

    NSString *missionViewController = [viewController stringByAppendingString:missionNo];

    Class controllerClass = NSClassFromString (missionViewController);
    id detailViewController = [[controllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"gameViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"missionViewController;%@",missionViewController);

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];


     detailViewController .which2 = which;


    }

}
```

everything work great except I want to pass a string from the first view controller to the second view controller which ever one that may be.

As you can see I have put in the code just above detailViewController.which2 = which;

I have created the property and synthesized NSString *which in my first view controller and NSString *which2 in all the subsequent view controllers.  in the first instance where mission is <1 everything works ok and NSLog shows the string being passed.  However with the second detailViewController (which is the variable view controller) I get the error Property 'which2' not found on object of type"_strong id'  Does anyone have any suggestion on how to resolve this?

the other viewControllers are gameViewController1, gameViewController2, etc.  Each is rather long and complex.  But they all load into the same xib file gameViewController.  There is a UIlabel that update to one higher once the user finishes that gameView so they can go on the the next on in the series or go back to the main menu.  If they go back to the main menu the number is added to "gameViewController" so the correct one is loaded.  So I can't specify which view controller is going to load since it depends on the user's place.  Thus the missionViewController with the # of mission added to load the correct view controller.   Each of the subsequent view controllers has a which2 created and synthesized.   What if we pretend that all subsequent view controllers just had a UILabel that is going to display the string "which2 in it.  All I want to do is pass the string "which" to the next viewController (whichever one that is) as "which2".

Comment: Can you post the controllerClass

Comment: can't add it is way to long to post it but I have edited my original post with some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic binding allows you to send messages to an `id` as long as the selector exists in the project, but dot-syntax is not allowed.

Changing

```
detailViewController.which2 = which;
```

to

```
[detailViewController setWhich2:which];
```

should suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Use Protools to update the value.

```
@protocol MissionProtocol
@required
-(void) updateValue:(NSSTring*) value;
@end
```

Implement the protocols in your ViewControllers. i.e.

```
@interface MissionViewController:UIViewController<MissionProtocol>
....
@end
```

In your implementation file, implement the method updateValue.

```
-(void) updateValue:(NSString*) value
{
   self.which2=value;
}
```

Then change your original code to:

```
 NSString *viewController = @"gameViewController";

    NSString *missionViewController = [viewController stringByAppendingString:missionNo];
    Class controllerClass = NSClassFromString (missionViewController);
    id<MissionProtocol> detailViewController = [[controllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"gameViewController" bundle:nil];
    [detailViewController updateValue:which];
```

Comment: This only makes a difference at compile time...it won't fix the error.

Comment: @John the difference in runtime would be "id" doesn't have a property "which2" whereas SuperMissionViewController has that. Why wouldn't that fix the error?

Comment: Actually, OP might be talking about a compile-time error (it's a bit hard to read). But in response to your comment, type-casting has 0 effect at runtime.

Comment: @John Spot on. OP must be getting a compile time error for trying to access "which2" var on an object of type "id". casting to a SuperViewController should solve that compile time error.

Comment: the original replay can't be done because as explained in updated post I don't know the name of the next ViewController since it will vary.

Answer (score 0):

write this : `detailViewController .which2 = which;

just before you push navigation controller.`